# PDFTron - get data from IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I'm using PDFTron library (javascript) to download files and store it inside indexedDB.
PDFTron use initOfflineDB to initializes the offline database. I would know I can get data inside indexedDb, I don't know db name to use html5 method.

Last question, is possible download .doc files? Is there a method to convert pdf, doc.. in xod type?

Thanks a lot guys and hava a good day.

Francesco.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to our offline library sample here https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/samples/offline-library/

As you can see unique document ids are required to store and retrieve your documents from indexedDB. Document interface 
(https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/lib/html5/doc/symbols/CoreControls.Document.html) provides methods to check if a file is already in storage `isDownloaded` or save it to the storage `storeOffline` etc

If you wish to inspect the indexedDB storage you could use Chrome Developer Tools -> Resources -> IndexedDB

In order to open Office files with WebViewer you would have to convert your files to .xod first with PDFNet SDK https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html or PWS https://www.pdftron.com/pws/

Comment: Thanks a lot :)), another question, is possibile download zip with pdftron?